# How to check ASP.NET authorization config from the code dynamically

Tags: asp.net, security, httpmodule

Working on custom authentication module for ASP.NET WebForms application. Almost finished but have one not implemented issue yet... how to check that authorized user has permission to get access to the page?

The application has web.config with:

```
  <location path="SomePage.aspx">
    <system.web>
      <authorization>
        <allow roles="Admin"/>
        <deny users="*"/>
      </authorization>
    </system.web>
  </location>
```

How to check from the custom HttpModule the page, that was just requested, allowed to be shown to authorized user?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

UrlAuthorizationModule.CheckUrlAccessForPrincipal

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.security.urlauthorizationmodule.checkurlaccessforprincipal.aspx

Comment: Perfecto! Exactly what I need!